# Flask form not getting values

Tags: python, html, flask

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="InputEmail" id="InputEmail" class="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder="Email"/>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="InputPassword" id="InputPassword" class="form-control input-sm chat-input"
           placeholder="Password"/>
    </br>
    <input type="text" name="InputConfirmPassword" id="InputConfirmPassword" class="form-control input-sm chat-input"
           placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
    </br>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="group-btn">  
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">SignUp</button>   
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my html code that contains the from tag from where I want to extract data, but I am not getting the email, password and confirm password field in Python! 
Here is my python code!

```
@app.route("/signup",methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    email = request.form.get('InputEmail')
    password = request.form.get('InputPassword')
    confirm_password = request.form.get('InputConfirmPassword')
    print str(email)
    print str(password)
    print str(confirm_password)
    return "You have signed up!"
```

All those print statement is giving me none. Any help with this problem please?

Comment: so when you print is there an error, or it just print blanks?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the syntax that's why it is not able to fetch the values from the HTML forms. Try using the code mentioned below.

```
@app.route("/signup",methods=['GET','POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['InputEmail']
        password = request.form['InputPassword']
        confirm_password = request.form['InputConfirmPassword']
        print str(email)
        print str(password)
        print str(confirm_password)
        return "You have signed up!"
    return render_template("html_file.html")
```

In the code above it will first render the template "html_file.html". And when we submit the form it will generate a POST request. After which it will enter the if block and your logic will get executed.